# TFIDF in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tf-idf

Hi below is my function to create tfidf matrix in python

```
def tf_idf(self,job_id,method='local'):
    jobtext = self.get_job_text ( job_id , method=method )
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( max_df=0.8 , max_features=200000 ,
                                        min_df=0.2 , stop_words='english' ,
                                        use_idf=True , tokenizer=self.tokenize_and_stem(jobtext), ngram_range=(1, 3) )
    #tfidf_vectorizer.fit(jobtext)
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(jobtext) #fit the vectorizer to synopses
    print(tfidf_matrix.shape)
```

and i am getting following error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
>   File ".../employment_skills_extraction-master/api/process_request.py", line 206, in <module>
> main()
>   File ".../employment_skills_extraction-master/api/process_request.py", line 202, in main
> print pr.process(json.dumps(test))
>   File ".../employment_skills_extraction-master/api/process_request.py", line 188, in process
> termVector=self.tf_idf(job_id)
>   File ".../employment_skills_extraction-master/api/process_request.py", line 174, in tf_idf
> tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(jobtext) #fit the vectorizer to synopses
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1285, in fit_transform
> X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 804, in fit_transform
> self.fixed_vocabulary_)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 739, in _count_vocab
> for feature in analyze(doc):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 236, in <lambda>
> tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
> ```

Please help why i am getting this Error?

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` looks like the relevant part of the error and it concerns your variable `job_id` which is probably not what you think it is. Whatever it is supposed to be it is probably instead a list (how long I don't know) which contains the thing you want.

If you insert a line on the second line of the function and change a variable name to keep it elegant like this:

```
job_id_element = job_id[0]
jobtext = self.get_job_text ( job_id_element , method=method )
```

it will probably work.

Just examine the contents of the variable `job_id` and consider whether you want the first element of it - the 0 as I wrote - or the last in which `len(job_id)` is what you need instead of 0, or maybe a different one.